# Google Apps Script - How to send HTML email from Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to write a code to send an html email from a Sheet. I have a template in a GAS html file. Gmail API is enabled.

I did manage to send an email this way, complete with replaced placeholders. However, I'm just sending all the text in the html file, tags and all.

```
function htmlTry() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sample");
  var lastRow     = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var name        = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  var problem     = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();

  if(problem == "Yes") {
    var htmlBody  = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlFile').getContent()
      .replace("#name", name)
      .replace("?name", name)
      .replace("/name", name);
      
    MailApp.sendEmail ("sample@email.com", "Problem: " + name, htmlBody);
  }
}
```

I've provided a sample of the html file as well. Which is exactly what the email says, except it loses the indents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Problem</title>
    <style>
        body,table,thead,tbody,tr,td,img {
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #23A5F3;
        }

        .wrapper {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p {
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
            color:#9CD6FA;
        }

        p,a,li {
            font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
            color:#000000;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
    <table width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="wrapper" width="600" align="center">
                    <table class="section header" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="column">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                                                <p style="text-align:justify;">Lorem ipsum</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Solved thanks to [Irvin Jay G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15384825/irvin-jay-g) who took the time to explain why I should have done exactly what they suggested, rather than thinking for myself. Hope you have a wonderful couple of days.

Comment: html without tags is just ascii text.  If you don't use tags then you can take advantage of the functionality of the tags.  But it would probably still work.

Comment: I think one of the easiest was to do this is with html templates and scriptlets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solution:***

> You need to use the advanced parameter called `htmlBody`, as per the MailApp's [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options) method, to show the file in html view instead of showing the pure html codes on the email message.

I was able to replicate your script and got this result on my test email account:

[image]

***Here's the tweaked script using the `htmlBody` advanced parameter:***

```
function htmlTry() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sample");
  var lastRow     = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var name        = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
  var problem     = spreadsheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue();

  if(problem == "Yes") {
    var htmlBody  = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlFile').getContent()
      .replace("#name", name)
      .replace("?name", name)
      .replace("/name", name);

    MailApp.sendEmail("sample@email.com", 'Problem: '+ name, htmlBody, {
    htmlBody: htmlBody
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: My template looks wonderfully bad like that, thank you for showing me. Your suggestion gives me an email that says "[object Object]".

Comment: Have you removed the "body" (the "name") parameter on structure of MailApp.sendEmail("sample@email.com", 'Problem: '+ name, name (<--this is the "body" parameter) , { htmlBody: htmlBody });? When you remove the body parameter on the sendEmail() method, this will only show the email body with [object Object] instead of showing the rendered HTML file, as this parameter is required when you have an advanced parameter to be used which is the "htmlBody." The body parameter will not be visible on the actual message anyways because it will be replaced by rendered HTML body.